# How does a person work with the BlastXML2 namespace on import?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, blast

The Xquery schema is shown here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/data_specs/schema_alt/NCBI_BlastOutput2.xsd (Outfmt = 16 on Blast+ command line).

The aim is to:

- Include search term (Just one for now, ideally any of a group)
- Exclude blacklist items (same as above)
- Filter on bitscore being above a certain threshold.

So far I have managed to filter on one search term and one blacklist item. But I had to do a very strange pathing to get there.

On the .xml document it is a simple path of `Hit/description/HitDescr/title` for example. You can see below that I had to repeatedly use `//*:title[1]` or what have you even once I'd pulled an item out, even when there's only one. This means the code breaks if I want to use 'Search' instead of 'Hit' and want to pull out the query name for the .csv.

I get an error saying title should be an item not a series but I've specified `title` as `[1]` and it's doing my head in. The error also goes got bit-score if the database has more than one .xml file in it for some strange reason. It worked for a database with exact one .xml file in.

```
declare namespace blast = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
declare variable $searchTerm as xs:string external := "virus";
declare variable $blacklist as xs:string external := "Phage";
declare variable $bitscore as xs:int external := 50;


let $options := map { 
                     'format' : 'xquery',
                     'header': true(),
                     'separator': 'comma'
                     }  

let $hits := //*:Hit

let $hasParams := for $hit in $hits
                  where $hit//*:title[1][not(text() contains text {$blacklist})] and $hit//*:title[1][text() contains text {$searchTerm}] and $hit//*:bit-score[1][data() > $bitscore]
                  return $hit  

let $data := map { 
'names' : ['species name', 'bitscore'],
'records' : (for $entry in $hasParams
return[string($entry//*:title), string($entry//*:bit-score)]
)
}

return file:write(
  '/tmp/output.csv',
  csv:serialize($data, $options)
                 )
```

This works fine and forms a basis for building the .csv I was previously using Python for (slow because I have an entire folder of .xml files to do at a time this way), it just seems wrong.

Comment: Feel free to send this to the basex-talk mailing list; it may require some iterations to be answered satisfactorily.

Comment: I'm feeling that may be the case! NCBI blast is sort of known for being a bit unwieldy to work with!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (but it's a bit of a guess because you don't describe the problem very precisely) that you're making the common mistake of writing `$hit//*:title[1]` when you meant `($hit//*:title)[1]`. The former expression selects every title that is the first title child of its parent.

Comment: Yeah, I can only apologise for the incoherent question; it's a case of being such a beginner that you don't know what I'm asking!The overall question was a case of why, with the database open, I need to use //*: to access the direct child of something, but I was accidentally also asking what I think you just answered. :) I do actually want to select the first 'title' child of the parent in this case because I just want the first (what should be ONLY) title child of each Hit.

Comment: It just percolated through what you meant after trying it based on 'try what the more experienced person suggests and then work out how later'. Your answer did work and I'm getting my head around how! I remain puzzled by why I have to access direct children using //*: though.

Comment: I can't really comment on that since you haven't shown us the XML that this query is running against: I'm commenting on something that I can't actually see.

Comment: I had to include the schema because the actual XML files are megabytes in size. I'm not certain there's a way to show you the actual contents of a file in a meaningful way that the schema's architecture can't without making the post very, very long. I'll try my best to cut something down and see if it behaves the same way.

Comment: If the files are too big, then that's also true of the schema. In such cases you need to simplify the problem to something that isn't going to take us 3 hours to understand. Remember, most people only allow about 5 minutes to read and understand your question.

Comment: That's a fair point. Someone above said that basex talk might be the place for this issue as it is quite difficult to break down the issue into small chunks. Thank you for your advice on the parentheses though!